# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {children}): ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

```
const Label = children => (
  <div className="label">{children}</div>
);

<Label>some text</Label>
```

This gives an error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
>   {children}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an
>   array instead.

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Reason for Objects are not valid as a React child?

Because here:

```
const Label = children => (
   <div className="label">{children}</div>
);
```

Children is just the argument name, it will have the values of props, and it will be an object, like this:

```
props = {
   children: .....
}
```

**Possible Solutions:**

Use destructuring and take out the children from props objects, it will work. Like this:

```
const Label = ( {children} ) => (
   <div className="label">{children}</div>
);
```

Or use `children.children` (actually it will be props.children):

```
const Label = children => (
   <div className="label">{children.children}</div>
);
```

Check working example (check the console log values you will get the better idea):

```js
const Label1 = (children) => {
   console.log(children);
   return <div className="label">{children.children}</div>
};

const Label2 = ({children}) => {
   console.log(children);
   return <div className="label">{children}</div>
};

ReactDOM.render(<div>
    <Label1>ABC</Label1>
    <Label2>ABC</Label2>
  </div>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: Thanks! Totally forgot about this...too tired to think

Comment: no problem, sometimes that happens, glad it solved your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a right way, Because, Your function's parameter has a Prop Object. 
Therefore, the variable `children` on your code is just Prop Object.

```
const Label = ({children}) => (
        <div className="label">{children} </div> 
    )
)
```

Hey, Do you know what is in that variable 'a' on my example??

```
let { a } = {a:1, b:2}
console.log(a)
// Output : ?     <= guess it.
```